# Dictionary Casting

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

Is it possible to cast an enumerated-key dictionary to an integer-key dictionary? (Or a copy constructor would work fine for what I'm doing as well.) In other words, something that looks like:

```
Dictionary<int, string> NewDictionary =
    (Dictionary<int, string>)OldDictionary<MyEnum, string>;
```

<sup>(Yes, I know that syntax isn't quite correct, it's just to show what it is I'm coming from.)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate over the dictionary and build a new one, transforming each key (e.g. by using the [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) extension) :

```
OldDictionary.ToDictionary(x => ((int)x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Yes, I am. Thanks for the various methods!

Comment: @Kikaimaru: Sure? I didn't actually check, just assumed it would be possibe. On the other hand, it would make sense not to allow this as it changes the semantics of the type significantly, for example you could get key collisions etc from casting and the hashing is differently, making the cast a ridiciously expensive operation.

Comment: well this would work if you could do that: ((Dictionary<object, string>)oldDictionary<string, string>).Add(7, "...");